# Condition to check select2 dropdown for mandatory field validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple select2 dropdowns and text fields,I need to do validation for text fields and dropdowns. I am able to validate the text fields but not the dropdown fields.

I have written a class for dropdown and text fields as MandatoryDD and MandatoryTxt.

I am able to validate all the text fields but unable to iterate through dropdown fields, is there any way to check the dropdown value(check the first dropdown value which is 'SELECT' option in my case or check the index number(0 in my case)

Answer (score 1):

Beacuse this.value will not return the value for selected option of dropdown . To get the selected option value of dropdown, try this -

```
jQuery(this).find("option:selected").val();
```

Comment: I want to get my first value of the dropdown i.e. SELECT and check the condition, if the user has not selected the dropdown value and still shows the first value as SELECT , throw a message.

Comment: Separate you each loop for dropdown. After that use the syntax which I have written in my answer..